# Nodejs: Decrypt data in php and rewrite this in node js

Tags: php, node.js, encryption, cryptography, pbkdf2

I  have some php decrypt code, and I want rewrite this decrypt in node js.

```
    $password         = "password";
    $salt             = "salt";   
    $data = "somebase64data"
    $prepared_key         = openssl_pbkdf2($password, $salt, 256, 65536, "sha256");
    $rtc             = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode(data),"AES-256-CBC", 
    $prepared_key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, "LQjFLCU3sAVplBC3");
    $rtc            = gzdecode($rtc);
    file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . '/log/tcs.new.crypt.' . $o . '.rtc.log', $rtc);
```

I try do this:

```
function decrypt(text, salt, iv) {
    const password = "password";
    crypto.pbkdf2(password, salt, 65536, 256, "sha256", (err, key) => {
      try {
        const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv("aes-256-cbc", key, iv);
        const decrypted = decipher.update(text, "base64", "binary");
        decrypted += decipher.final("binary");
      } catch (error) {
        throw new Error(error)
      }
    });
  }
  decrypt(plainText, salt, iv);
```

And then I have this error: Invalid key length.
I know that my key after pbkdf2 is a buffer with a length of 256 bytes. But the createDecipheriv function expects a key with a length of 32 bytes

Comment: Are you using the correct `iv`? Which line exactly give you the `Invalid key length` error?

Comment: Yes. I use correct `iv`. Line `const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv("aes-256-cbc", key, iv);`.And this error refers to `internal/crypto/cipher.js:92`

Comment: Did you check that the value of `key` (in JS) and `$prepared_key` (in PHP) are the same?

Comment: Yes. I checked. `$prepared_key` (php) is a string by default, and has 256 length. By default `key`(js) is a buffer, and when I do `key.toString()` i get the same string, but this string has 243 length

Comment: Did you try to pass the key as a string (`key.toString()`) and set the length to `243`?

Comment: Yes, I tried. But a have the same error `invalid key length`. I think it means that `createDecipheriv` function expects a 32-byte long buffer as the second parameter, but my key is 256-byte long

Comment: Just use a 32 byte key, as required by AES-256-CBC.

Comment: Okay. But if I use 32 byte key, I had another error, bad decrypt :)) but why in php does this work with a string of length 256, if aes-256-cbc required key with 32 byte long?)

Comment: PHP's openssl_encrypt/decrypt functions accept arbitrary sized keys. if the key is larger than the specified key size then only the first part of it is used, and if it is shorter it is padded with zeroes. So, even though you passed a 256 byte key, only the first 32 bytes were used. About the bad decrypt error, I think it is caused by invalid padding, which can happen for a number of reasons (incorrect key, IV, encoding/decoding).

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you help me with one more thing? After successful decryption I want to decode from gzip. In php we have `gzdecode()` build in function.  What is the analogue of this function in node js?

Comment: Please don't add add on questions in the comments - we're not consultants and this is not a discussion forum. If you have solved the initial question then you can post an answer yourself, or ask @t.m.adam to write one (and then possibly add your code to it).

Comment: Sorry for that((